# Matrix operations performed with column-vectors

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

We have 3 matrices: `m1`, `m2` and `b`. We want to apply matrix operations (dot or sum) in a particular way: we want to treat the columns of `m2` and `b` separately as a *vectors* and `m1` as a matrix.

`m1` is a (9*9) matrix:

```
m1 = {{0, 0.25, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0.25, 0, 0.25, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0,0},
      {0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0}, {0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0.25, 0,0},
      {0, 0.25, 0, 0.25, 0, 0.25, 0, 0.25, 0}, {0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0.25, 0, 0,0, 0.25},
      {0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0.25, 0, 0.25},
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0.25, 0}}
```

[image]

`m2` and `b` are (9*15) and (9*9) matrices, respectively, with the elements:

```
m2 = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},   
     {0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0}, 
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

b = {{1.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.5, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.5}}
```

We want to be able to extract any column of `m2` and `b` as a *vector*

[image]
[image]

in a such way, that we will be able to form the product `m1` with any extracted *vector* of `m2` and add it to an extracted column of `b` in the following way:

```
column[2][m2] = m1.column[1][m2] + column[1][b]

column[3][m2] = m1.column[2][m2] + column[2][b]

column[4][m2] = m1.column[3][m2 ]+ column[3][b]

column[i][m2] = m1.column[i - 1][m2] + column[i - 1][b]
```

and so on.

Finally we wanted to populate the matrix m2 with the newly calculated elements instead of zeros.

Comment: This seems to be precisely what you would get by just doing `m1.m2 + b` and extracting the columns of the result.

Comment: With this way, all result will be 'b' because at the first step, m2 is a zero matrix. As long as I want to get column[i][m2]=m1.column[i-1][m2]+column[i-1][b]

Comment: Actually, `m2` vanishes. So the result can be taken to be the columns of `b` alone, right?

Comment: After the first step, the first column of m2 will not be zero and some elements of b fills them, for calculating the second column of m2 we need the first column (of m2) which is not zero at this step then m2 can not be vanished in the continuous process.

Comment: Oh, I get it. So `m2` is the "storage" for the results...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your algorithm is reproduced by this line:

```
m2 = Transpose[FoldList[m1.#1 + #2 &, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},  
      Transpose[b]]];

MatrixForm[m2]
```

> [image: matrix]

Here I use [`FoldList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FoldList.html) to implement the iterative application of `m1` to a vector, starting with zero (`{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`, which is the first column of `m2` to begin with and will also be the first column in the result), and the addition of successive columns of `b`. The columns of `b` are first converted to rows by [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Transpose.html) so that each original column is an element in a list that can be fed to `FoldList` as the last argument.

In the matrix operation `m1.#1 + #2 &`, the `#1` stands for the vector on which `m1` acts. The resulting vector is a row vector (i.e., a one-level `List`). The second argument `#2` is also a row vector obtained from `Transpose[b]`, i.e., a column of `b`. The `FoldList` command collects the resulting row vectors in a new `List` of rows. But finally we want this list of rows to be represented as columns of a matrix. This is what the outermost `Transpose` is for.

The important thing to understand is `FoldList`. It iterates exactly  as many times as there are elements in the last argument, `Transpose[b]`. That is, in our case, nine times. This gives you the freedom to have an arbitrary number of columns in `b`. Since `m2` is the matrix that stores the iterative results, it can have only as many columns as there are iterations, so its dimension is not $9\times 15$ if `b` has $9$ columns. Instead, the column dimension of `m2` is then $10$ because the first column is the original zero vector.

Comment: thank you so much for your immediate response, please let me check for my case.